# HTML video is not visible inside a foreignObject in svg

Tags: javascript, html, svg, video

My HTML video is not visible inside a foreignObject in svg. What am I doing wrong here?

HTML:

```
<div id="drawRegion">

</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
#drawRegion {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

Javascript:

```
debugger;
const svg = d3.select("#drawRegion")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%");
svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", "0")
  .attr("y", "0")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .attr("fill", "yellow");

const fObj = mainSvg
  .append("foreignObject");

fObj
  .attr("x", "20%")
  .attr("y", "10%")
  .attr("width", "60%")
  .attr("height", "80%");

  const vidObj = fObj
  .append("xhtml:video");
  vidObj
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .attr("href", "https://archive.org/download/BigBuckBunny_124/Content/big_buck_bunny_720p_surround.mp4");
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76uedo40/404/).

I checked that the `foreignObject` is actually created and takes place it is supposed to, so I would expect the video just appear over there and fill it (`foreignObject`), but this does not happen, so I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[videos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) require a child source element.

You also have a syntax error that mainSvg does not exist which I've corrected too.

```js
const svg = d3.select("#drawRegion")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%");
svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", "0")
  .attr("y", "0")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .attr("fill", "yellow");

const fObj = svg
  .append("foreignObject");

fObj
  .attr("x", "20%")
  .attr("y", "10%")
  .attr("width", "60%")
  .attr("height", "80%");
  
  const vidObj = fObj
  .append("xhtml:video");
  vidObj
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%")

  
  const src = vidObj.
  append("xhtml:source");
  src
    .attr("type", "video/mp4")
    .attr("src", "https://archive.org/download/BigBuckBunny_124/Content/big_buck_bunny_720p_surround.mp4");
```

```css
#drawRegion {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="drawRegion">

</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: In Google Chrome there is a black rectangle instead of the video. Is it a Google chrome bug?

Comment: Presumably. Try Firefox and click on the rectangle to start the video.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to above Robert Longson's solution, it worked for me when I add "controls" attribute

```
let vidObj = fObj
              .append("xhtml:video");
            
              vidObj
              .attr("width", "100%")
              .attr("height", "100%")
              .attr("controls", false)
```